# split huge text file and write as separate text files based on character

Tags: text, vbscript

I have huge .txt file, it's around 500MB produced daily by my web apps, it has 21 fields in a row, separated by pipe character *|* in each field and it has more 2 million rows in it.
for speed case, I split the input file by its size and now need to be split by character branch field that i'm about to add this new field.

```
'previous header
    Date|Field_2|Field_3|Field_4|Field_5|Field_6|Field_7|Field_8|Field_9|Field_10|Field_11|Field_12|Field_13|Field_14|Field_15|Field_16|Field_17|Field_18|Field_19|Field_20|

'after add branch field
Date|Branch|Field_2|Field_3|Field_4|Field_5|Field_6|Field_7|Field_8|Field_9|Field_10|Field_11|Field_12|Field_13|Field_14|Field_15|Field_16|Field_17|Field_18|Field_19|Field_20|


'i used to split use this code:
'got the script from http://prabhuram.com/articles/2012/02/28/splitting-large-files-using-vbscript/

Dim  Counter
Const InputFile = "C:\input.txt"
Const OutputFile = "C:\output"
Const RecordSize = 1000000 
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (InputFile, ForReading)
Counter = 0
FileCounter = 0
Set objOutTextFile = Nothing

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    if Counter = 0 Or Counter = RecordSize Then
        Counter = 0
        FileCounter = FileCounter + 1
    if Not objOutTextFile is Nothing then objOutTextFile.Close        
    Set objOutTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( OutputFile & "_" & FileCounter & ".txt", ForWriting, True)
    end if
    strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
    objOutTextFile.WriteLine(strNextLine)
    Counter = Counter + 1
Loop
objTextFile.Close
objOutTextFile.Close
Msgbox "Done..."
```

the code works 100% by splitting every RecordSize = 1000000 rows, now I want some improvement by adding new field (Branch) for report by branch and split the huge file into separate output file based on Branch code (example branch code: AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD etc).
the input file already sorted by branch, so no need more *sort/order by* procedure in the script.

one huge .txt file --> separate .txt file based on branch code and the output file would be the branch code it self. (for exp.: AAA.txt and so on..).

Any idea, how can I accomplish this using VBscript?

Comment: What if I change the delim for pipe to comma?

Comment: no, it can't be changed, since it's client requirement. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write to multiple files identified by your branch code. I'd probably use a dictionary for managing them, e.g. like this:

```
...

Set outFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
  line = objTextFile.ReadLine

  branchCode = Split(line, "|")(1)
  If Not outFiles.Exists(branchCode) Then
    outFiles.Add branchCode, fso.OpenTextFile(outputFile _
      & "_" & branchCode & ".txt", ForWriting, True)
  End If

  outFiles(branchCode).WriteLine line
Loop

For Each branchCode In outFiles.Keys
  outFiles(branchCode).Close
Next

...
```

Adjust the name of the output files as you see fit.

Comment: Correct/Nice solution that deserves better than "can't get it to work".